# How browser handles some tags as "allow overlap" and others as "do not allow"

Tags: html

```html
<br><b>ABCDEF<u>GHJIKLOM</b>PQRST</u>UVWXYZ
<br><b>ABCDEF<ins>GHJIKLOM</b>PQRST</ins>UVWXYZ
```

See how in the first example the underline goes down to `T` and in the second one it abruptly ends at `M`. But the code is basically identical, except that `u` is supposed to change particular look and `ins` is just a hint that text was inserted and should be marked "somehow", OK it is marked as underline. Experience tells me that this must be OK, but I just wonder why some tags allow to be overlapped with some other tags and paired to some others are not allowed to be overlapped? Is there a table of pairs somewhere inside the browser? Or some tags are marked as "overlap-friendly"? Why is this?

Comment: Intriguing. ... but I feel too open-ended for SO.

Comment: Don't find much on the internet about this, the prevailing view is to just not do it - don't nest tags since it's invalid syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither snippet is valid. The browser is having to reconstruct a valid DOM tree from your input; in these two cases, it is ending up with:

```
<b>
    ABCDEF
    <u>
        GHJIKLOM
    </u>
</b>
<u>
    PQRST
</u>
UVWXYZ
```

and

```
<b>
    ABCDEF
    <ins>
        GHJIKLOM
    </ins>
</b>
PQRSTUVWXYZ
```

The algorithm which controls recovery from invalid HTML input like this is specified in [section 12.2.3.3 ("Parse state") of the HTML5 standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#the-list-of-active-formatting-elements).

What's specifically causing the difference in results here is that the `<ins>` tag is **not** classified by HTML5 as a formatting element, whereas `<b>` and `<i>` are. (The full list of formatting elements is given [in section 12.2.3.2](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#formatting), and is quite small.) This causes the `<ins>` to not be reopened when it is "interrupted" by another closing tag.